# Eclipse source code folder changed

Tags: eclipse

I'm using eclipse Helios with several projects on the same workspace.
When the source code folder changes eclipse gives an error about "cannot find files" which is OK, but there is no option to tell it where the files are now.
I need to delete the project and create a new one.
This takes time because projects reference others, they have non-standard makefiles which take time to configure in eclipse.

I can't seem to find an answer for this anywhere on the internet.

Comment: I suppose you could point eclipse to the folders, but perhaps better, would be to create the folders within eclipse. otherwise there should be an option to import the folders.

Comment: also see this link "setting source folders" http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_set_src_fold.htm

Answer (score 0):

If your source folder changed, go to Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Source -- remove your old source folder and pick a new one.

[image]